# Storing Face Indices in Data Arrays

Tags: python, scripting

I am fairly new to python scripting in Blender. I am creating a tool for my workflow and can't seem to figure out several elements, although I do know how to do them in other languages.

I can get the index numbers of the faces in an object. How would I store faces selected in a variable or array that can be accessed after edit mode is exited?

Comment: You might want to consider using a [data layer](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#customdata-access) approach.  Saving face indexes in a list for example could provide misleading results when faces are added / removed during an edit.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate a data layer approach. I have tried to use global variables to store the index of a face to be accessible by other functions, but that doesn't seem to work. Basically, I'm trying to select faces, store them in a variable, so that if I close Blender and reopen it, I can perform an operation on those faces regardless of what additional faces are selected/ not selected on a mesh. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Storing custom data on a face**

Example adds an int layer, named "Selection" to the context object mesh (in edit mode) and assigns each faces corresponding layer value to 1 if selected else 0.

This data is stored "on" the face, it will be lost if the face is deleted, but will remain the same if the face indices are re-sorted.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

# custom int property on face
selectionlayer = bm.faces.layers.int.get("Selection")
if not selectionlayer:  # create one
    selectionlayer = bm.faces.layers.int.new("Selection")

# assign 1 if face selected else 0
for f in bm.faces:
    f[selectionlayer] = int(f.select)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
```

Save and close, reopen and run, and there will still be an int prop assoc with each face that will match the selection when above was run.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
obj = context.object
mesh = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

# get the custom layer
customlayer = bm.faces.layers.int.get("Selection")
if customlayer:  # create one
    # print face index, layer value 
    for f in bm.faces:
        print("face %d " % f.index, f[customlayer])
```

Comment: Oh wow. I'll have to study that for a bit. So "Selection" is a variable that is initialized as it is assigned to the variable "selectionlayer"?

Comment: How are you assigning 1 if a face/ faces are selected? Is it it the array data from f.select? Are you saying it's true if any faces are selected, or is 1 an actual property? Lastly, are you saying that anything that is entered into the data layer "Selection" is automatically stored for global use?

Comment: The code under the comment `# assign 1 if face selected else 0`  If the face is selected then the data layer prop for that face is set to 1, 0 otherwise.  It is  storing the layer data on the mesh, and is saved to that mesh with `bm.to_mesh` or `bmesh.updata_edit_mesh`.  The second script shows that the selection is saved.

Comment: VERY nice batFINGER. Are you using int(f.select) as a strong type instead of using f.select?

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize it's an int layer as there is no bool layer.   `1 if f.select else 0` could be another way.  Doesn't matter too much,  as python is very forgiving on type.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the list of indices in a list object (array), it will be accessible even after the object is no longer in edit mode.

```
import bpy, bmesh

o = bpy.context.object

# Create bmesh object. This particular method requires that the object will be in edit mode.
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( o.data )

# Store list of selected face indices in object (will be empty if not face is selected)
selected_faces_list = [ f.index for f in bm.faces if f.select ]

# Go to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )

# Print content of list to show that it still contains face indices although we are now in object mode
print( selected_faces_list )
```

Comment: Thanks! But I guess I should add more clarity to the question. How do I store a selected face index (or several) in a global variable or an array so that I can access that index after it is no longer selected visibly? Kind of like how materials work, where after assigning a material, you can make changes to those specific faces- though they are not selected visibly.

Comment: So you want to use this data by a piece of code that will run at a separate time and not immediately after you've selected the faces? If so, see this page for examples how you create your own globally accessed property group: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_release/info_overview.html#inter-classes-dependencies