# Weight-paint vertices without mesh in 2.81

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights, point-clouds

Context: I'm trying to annotate point cloud data.

Is there a way to weight paint individual vertices that are not in a mesh?
In the image below, all vertices belong to the vertex group 'Group'. However, only the vertices that are connected by a mesh are weight-paintable.
[image: example]

How can I weight-paint the individual vertices as well?

Comment: Can assign vertex weights in vertex groups edtt box. To annotate would look into mesh data layers.  see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70729/15543 (for faces) but same applies for vertices.

Comment: @Aventau Have you figured out any way around this? I guess you could create a script that regularly renders a semi-transparent sphere around each vertex, based on its weight.